# How to apply condition to a string in the multiple string with powershell

Tags: powershell, split, file-get-contents, get-childitem, new-item

I am trying to make a txt file and apply some content to a multiple string

this is what I did so far:

```
$Filename = "Jessica,Jimmy,Adam"
$Content = ({Whoisthesmartest=})
$Splitname = get-childitem $Filename -split "," 
new-item c:\test.txt -itemtype file -value $Content + $Splitname
```

But that didn't work.

what I'm trying to achieve is a txt file that has content:

```
Whoisthesmartest=Jessica
Whoisthesmartest=Jimmy
Whoisthesmartest=Adam
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to process the elements of array `$SplitName` individually, which you can do by enumerating it in the pipeline ...
- ... processing each element via [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) ...
- ... and saving the results to an output file with [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Set-Content)

  - Note that `Set-Content` quietly overwrites an existing file, which [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/New-Item) only does if you add `-Force`.

```bash
$Filename = "Jessica,Jimmy,Adam"
$Content = 'Whoisthesmartest='    # Note: Use a *string*, not {...}
$Splitname = $Filename -split "," # No need for Get-ChildItem - unless I'm missing something.

$Splitname | 
  ForEach-Object { $Content + $_ } |
  Set-Content c:\test.txt
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$Content = ({Whoisthesmartest=})`

This assigns a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) (needlessly wrapped in `(...)`) to `$Content`, whereas you're looking for a *string*:

```bash
$Content = 'Whoisthesmartest='
```

> `... -value $Content + $Splitname`

`$Content + $Splitname` is an *expression*, and in order for an expression to function as a *command argument*, it must be *enclosed in `(...)`*:

```bash
... -value ($Content + $Splitname)
```

> `$Splitname = get-childitem $Filename -split ","`

Since `$SplitName` is a *string* you want to split, there's no reason to involve [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-ChildItem); apart from that, the statement has the same problem as described above: expression `$Filename -split ","` lacks `(...)` enclosure.